# Simple React file upload, form data not appending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-hooks, use-effect

```
     const [image, setImage] = useState({ preview: "", file: "" });
     const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target.files.length) {
          setImage({
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
            file: e.target.files[0],
          });
        }
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", image.file);
        console.log(formData);
      }, [image]);
```

In the above code `console.log(formData);` returns empty object, unable to send file on axios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot print `FormData` to see the entries.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

You need to get it with key: `formData.get('file')` should give you what you need to verify.